# How to make Logstash consume its own logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Basically, I would like LogStash to consume its own logs and populate fields such as `@timestamp`, `level`, etc. for use in Kibana.

My current config looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/logstash/logs/*.log"
    type => "logstash"
  }
}
```

That seems hard to do -- without reverting to writing a Grok filter. Is that really the case that LogStash can't consume its own logs? (Hard to Google and I couldn't find anything.)

Or is this the wrong approach in the first place?

Example log output from LogStash:

```
{
  :timestamp=>"2014-09-02T10:38:08.798000+0200", 
  :message=>"Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones",
  :level=>:warn
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to resort to use `grok` because logstash is not able to use `rubydebug` as an input codec.

The logs are in a fixed format, so the `grok` to do it is straight forward.  We then use `date` to replace `@timestamp`

```
filter {
  grok {
      match => ["message", '{:timestamp=>"(?<timestamp>.*)", :message=>"(?<msg>.*)", :level=>:(?<level>.*)}']
  }
  mutate {
      replace => ["message", "%{msg}" ]
      remove_field => msg
  }
  date {
      match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
      remove_field => 'timestamp'
  }
}
```

The `mutate` step is needed because if you just put `<message>` into the match, it'll turn `message` into an array and add the extracted message to it, so capture as a different name and then replace the message.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do like that. 
Please save your logstash console log to a file. 
Then, you can use `ruby filter` or `grok filter` to parse out the information.

Here is the example:

```
input {
    file {
            path => "/path/to/logstash/logs/*.log"
    }
}

filter {
    ruby {
            code => "
                    mes = event['message'];
                    startPos = mes.index('level=>');
                    endPos = mes.length;
                    event[':level'] = mes[startPos+7..endPos-2];
            "
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
            codec => "rubydebug"
    }
}
```

Comment: But is that really the only way? Excuse me, but it seems like a hack to something that should be supported by LogStash directly.
A logging framework that can't read its own logs?? :-)